# iOS with iframe cannot show the H5 webpage

Tags: ios, objective-c, vue.js, mobile, wkwebview

Me and my classmate, we're working together. I use WKWebView（Objective-C） to acquire his H5 webpage. Now I can get other pages without iframe, but when  He used Vue.js with iframe, I can get nothing but a white page. Whereas there is no problem with Android and Web on PC.I didn't use Cordova, I wonder what should we do to make it works on iOS?

Comment: By the way, I get an NSURLErrorDomain code=-999， which means the request has been cancelled. I don't know why......

Comment: with your little infos we cant tell. Cache policy, user consent, timeout, missing html feature, etc etc

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.